# ASP.NET MVC GIS based application Scalability

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, gis, scalability, geoserver

I implemented a Web-GIS application with ASP.NET MVC, PostgreSQL database and GeoServer as a Map Server.

My application users will grow up as it goes public (Currently it's used internally by the organization, not public). I would like to know what are the scopes of the application that I should care about in order to add scalability in my project?

Here are the things that I've already done:

**Map Server:**

- Scaling out by adding servers for the Map Server (GeoServer)
- TileCache Server

**ASP.NET MVC:**

- Using Cache in the ASP.NET MVC
- Lazy loading (Entity framework and C# Lazy class)

**PostgreSQL:**

- Spatial Indexes
- VACUUM

However, I wouldn't like to scale up the system by adding hardware (ex: Increasing the size of the memory or etc).

So, Is there anything else that I should consider in my project for adding scalability into it?

Comment: Using a decoupled architecture is helpful. Maybe adopt something like micro services type of pattern.  You can also use compression tools like gzip to serve up static content.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the response. Where should I use gzip? as I know, we can add this into the web application. Can I use it in order to compress the returned map image from the `Map Server` (`GeoServer`)?

Comment: A quick google tells me that GeoServer uses compression out of the box. But you might want to look into that.  Your web app can be configured to serve/accept gzip at the IIS level. Again, a quick google will walk you through these steps.

Comment: @Mark Ok, Thanks for your time. I will search around the `decoupled architecture`. Thanks!